# GZip For ASP.NET WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, gzip

I am using the [Plugin](https://github.com/azzlack/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.MessageHandlers.Compression) for GZIP Compression of ASP.NET WebAPI Responses.

**Problem:**

Getting error as below:

> The type or namespace name 'GZipCompressor' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have added the Packages and used it under the "Global.asax.cs" file under the method: **`Application_Start()`

**What I tried:**

Added the below Namespaces in the "Global.asax.cs" file:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Extensions.Compression.Server;
using System.Net.Http.Extensions.Compression.Client;
```

**NOTE:** The namespace `using System.Net.Http.Extensions.Compression.Client;` is not getting resolved.

Which means If I type `System.Net.Http` in Visual Studio, I could get the `Http` namespace in **Global.asax.cs**

**My Application_Start Method:**

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Code that runs on application startup
   BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

   GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

   GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Insert(0, new ServerCompressionHandler(new GZipCompressor(), new DeflateCompressor()));
}
```

.NET Framework Version is 4.6.1

Is there any other way to compress the WebAPI Result with GZIP without using Plugins?

Answer (score 1):

I went to the plugin project link and installed

[image]

I added the line you mentioned  `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Insert(0, new ServerCompressionHandler(new GZipCompressor(), new DeflateCompressor()));`

and it didn't compile. But I did have to add the following using statements in the `Global.asax.cs`

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Extensions.Compression.Server;
using System.Net.Http.Extensions.Compression.Client;
using System.Net.Http.Extensions.Compression.Core.Compressors;
```

And it compiled. I don't know if that answers your question... but I hope it helps.